# How to set Unique open tracking in sendgrid with php

Tags: php, sendgrid-api-v3

The following code I am using to send mails from php.

```
<?php
     require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
     $email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
     $email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
     $email->addTo("test@example.com", "Example User");
     $email->setOpenTracking(true, "--sub--");
     $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
     $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
?>
```

Here I am setting Open Tracking for web-hook, When an email is opened the open event trigger and response coming to my given URL. Here I am getting web-hook every time when ever that email is opened by client. But I want Unique Open tracking.
I tried this which not working and may be invalid method:

```
     $email->setUniqueOpenTracking(true, "--sub--");
```

Is there any setting or parameters That I need to configure.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

After call conversation with send grid, they are not providing Unique open tracking.
I have to maintain the opened web-hooks in a table and check every time, whether the web-hook is already received or not.